# Hybrid-sleep fails with high memory usage

Tags: systemd, suspend, hybrid-sleep

I have hybrid-sleep mapped to my laptop lid closing in /etc/systemd/logind.conf:

```
HandleLidSwitch=hybrid-sleep
```

If my memory usage is too high when I close the lid, the suspend will never take place. I assume this is a result of my swap partition being smaller than the RAM in use, and so the hibernation function doesn't work properly.

Every once in a while, if I don't watch my laptop go to sleep, I'll find it running the next time I take it out of my bag (which could have been after hours of heating up in a case).

Is there any way to default to a regular suspend if my memory usage precludes hibernation? I'd rather not have to expand my swap space to solve this.

Comment: Hybrid-sleep needs a swap space to work. Some details [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7822/170). What system are you using?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. This only occurs when the memory usage exceeds swap space. I'm running Arch kernel 3.14 with 24gb RAM on btrfs with a 10 gb swap.